# How to create a file by using path string of this file which is in jar?

Tags: java, file, path, resources

I created an application with eclipse using this schema:

- App

  - src

    - package

      - a.java
  - resources

    - xmls

      - b.xml

In a.java, I create and use a file with this code:

```
File file = new File("resources/xmls/b.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(file);
```

This code work well in Eclipse but when I create runnable jar, I get this error (I used command prompt for run this file):

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\PROJECTS\App\build\dist\resources\xmls\b.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
...
```

jar file location is

```
D:\PROJECTS\App\build\dist
```

It seems that it try to find resources folder at the directory where jar is located.
My question, how to give this b.xml file path string as parameter to File for runnable jar?

Comment: Yes I tried, but it doesn't work, same error.

Comment: Say you run it with `java -jar app.jar path/to/file.xml` you'd get this param with `File xmlFile = new File(args[0]);`. You could also use an absolute path. Relative ones will be relative to your `.jar`.

Comment: In jar file, there are two folder: package folder and xmls folder

Comment: I use just java -jar app.jar

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `public URL getResource(String name)` method of **ClassLoader** class which :

> Finds the resource with the given name. A resource is some data
>   (images, audio, text, etc) that can be accessed by class code in a way
>   that is independent of the location of the code. The name of a
>   resource is a '/'-separated path name that identifies the resource.
>   This method will first search the parent class loader for the
>   resource; if the parent is null the path of the class loader built-in
>   to the virtual machine is searched. That failing, this method will
>   invoke findResource(String) to find the resource.

So your code will look like this :

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("xmls/b.xml").getFile());
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(file);
document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
//System.out.println("####Root element : " + document.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
```

---

### Edit

I've created the same structure as you with an xml example file that contains

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

And in the print out I got : *#### Root element : note*, I can share with you the code if you want. Anyway make sure that you have permission on your space and that your path is will formatted ! ( I'm using linux machine, **no windows no problems :D** ! )

Comment: I get this error: `D:\PROJECTS\build\dist\file:\D:\PROJECTS\build\dist\App.jar!\xmls\b.xml (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)`

Comment: My resources is not in src folder